# sqoop incremental job is failing due to org.kitesdk.data.DatasetOperationException

Tags: oracle, sqoop, parquet

I am trying to import data from oracle to hive table using sqoop incremental job, using parquet file format. But job is failing due to below error

> Error: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetOperationException: Failed to append
>   {"CLG_ID": "5",.....19/03/27 00:37:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :
>   attempt_15088_130_m_000_2, Status : FAILED

Query to create saved job:

> sqoop job -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://xxxxx
>   --create job1 -- import  --connect "jdbc:oracle:thinxxxxxx" --verbose --username user1 --password-alias alisas --query "select CLG_ID,.... from CLG_TBL where \$CONDITIONS"  --as-parquetfile --incremental
>   append --check-column CLG_TS  --target-dir /hdfs/clg_data/ -m 1

import query :

> sqoop job -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks:/xxxxx
>   --exec job1 -- --connect "jdbc:oracle:xxx"
>   --username user1 --password-alias alisas --query "select CLG_ID,.... from CLG_TBL where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /hdfs/clg_data/ -m 1
>   --hive-import --hive-database clg_db --hive-table clg_table --as-parquetfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is a known issue. We have faced with same problem a couple of weeks ago and
found this.

Here is the [link](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/release-notes/content/known_issues.html).

Description of the problem or behavior

In HDP 3, managed Hive tables must be transactional (hive.strict.managed.tables=true). Transactional tables with Parquet format are not supported by Hive. Hive imports with --as-parquetfile must use external tables by specifying --external-table-dir.

**Associated error message**

*Table db.table failed strict managed table checks due to the
following reason: Table is marked as a managed table but is not
transactional. 
Workaround*

When using **--hive-import** with **--as-parquetfile**, users must also provide **--external-table-dir** with a fully qualified location of the table:

**sqoop import ... --hive-import
                 --as-parquetfile 
                 --external-table-dir hdfs:///path/to/table**

Comment: Thanks, will try this solution